# jquery hover: Using a function and passing arguments makes it run immediately

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

In short, 
this works --> http://jsfiddle.net/mammolastan/ccafu/3/

this doesn't --> http://jsfiddle.net/mammolastan/2mZVu/

I am using jQuery hover.

In Example 1, function append(e) will only run upon mouse hover, which is what I want.

However, as shown in Example 2, when I try to pass an argument to function append(e), append(e) runs immediately on page load, and the script does not work.

I have tried looking for other examples of jquery hover problems, but I could not find any that were calling an existing function, I could only find examples where the function was defined in the hover call.

Ex1 is-->

```
 <html>
    <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>
    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
    </ul>
    <script>

$("li").hover(append,remove);
$("li.fade").hover(flash);

function append(e)

{
    alert(e);
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
}

function remove(e)
{
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
}

function flash(e)
{   $(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);   
}

</script>
```

Ex 2 is only changed here -->

```
$("li").hover(append('some string'),remove);
```

Comment: Adding the parenthesis executes the function immediately, referencing the function without parenthesis executes it when the event is triggered. This is basic javascript and not specific for .hover().

Comment: You have the choice: $("li").hover(function(){append('some string')},remove);  or $("li").hover(append,remove);

Comment: Oh, thank you, that is vital information I should know! So I will need to figure out some way to pass a string to append when append is called other than this method.

Comment: Then you have to use an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

As adeneo said, adding the parenthesis executes the function immediately.

One way to pass the argument is to add an attribut on the HTML element

```
<li text="some text" >Milk</li>
```

And then add your listener

```
$("li").hover(append, remove);
```

Your append function will look like this

```
function append()
{
    node = $(this);
node.append("<span>"+node.attr('text')+"</span>");
}
```

Here's the fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/2mZVu/7/

An other way is to call an anonymus function. You can pass the `currentTarget` element with your string:

```
$("li").hover(function(e){append(e.currentTarget, 'somestring')}, remove);
```

Then, you will have 2 argument in your function : the target and the string. Your function will look like this :

```
function append(e,a)
{
    $(e).append("<span>"+a+"</span>");
}
```

Here's the fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/2mZVu/7/

That beign said, I really dislike the second method since the code isnt clean. I don't know about optimisation, but I'm pretty sure the first method is faster.

Cheer

Comment: Thanks! I used the method that @roasted mentioned! Simple, easy peezy!

$("li").hover(function(){append('some string')},remove);

I did not realize that adding the argument to the function would make it run immediately.

Comment: Ahah as long as it worked, and i just realised that I copied the wrong code for the second method, sorry! Edited just for futur reference.